# How to get raw bytestring from AudioSegment

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, byte, pydub

Hello I'm trying to get the raw bytestring out of pydub AudioSegment.

I've already tried following:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file="../source/myfile.mp3")
bytestring = sound.raw_data
```

and

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file="../source/myfile.mp3")
bytestring = sound._data
```

but in my case it returns always a bytestring of with len 686866320 Bytes.

if I export it instead to a bytes array like following:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file="../source/myfile.mp3")
bytes = io.BytesIO()
bytes = sound.export(bytes, format='mp3')
```

I'm getting a much smaller len of 62301665.

At the end I'd like to have a **bytestring** and it's **real size** which (in my case is the real filesize of 62301665) but I cannot figure out how export reduces / compresses the data. The plain datastring of `sound.raw_data` cannot be played either.

Thank you for any help :)